# how convert recursive method to nonrecursive in java

Tags: recursion

I am trying to get the combination of five numbers which sum is equal to 20 and whose average  value equal to some specified value.

my code is

```
package Others;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

 public class RandomNumbers {

/**
 * @param args
 */
// Max average = 3.6 ///Min average=2.2
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Integer> i = getNumbers();
}

public static List<Integer> getNumbers() {
    List<Integer> n = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int rr = r.nextInt(10);
        n.add(rr);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n.size(); j++) {
        sum += n.get(j);
        average += ((j + 1) * n.get(j));
        System.out.println(n.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println("Avearge:" + average / 20);
    if (sum == 20 && (average / 20) == 2.1) {
        getCombination(n);
    } else {
        getNumbers();
    }
    return n;
}

public static void getCombination(List<Integer> n) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
        total += n.get(i);
        if (n.get(i) == 0) {
            getNumbers();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item: " + i + ":" + n.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total:" + total);
}
  }
```

it is working fine for average values from 2.2 to 3.6. When we give other number which is not in between 2.2 and 3.6 it is giving the error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)`package Others;
```

I Searched in some sites and some of them suggested to that avoid recursive and use iterators.But I am in confusion how to redevelop this program using iterators.

It is required my project . 
Any help would be appreciated. Please help me.

Comment: Would you prefer to use recursion?  There is no need to switch to iteration, if you like recursion.  Just remove the bugs.  Start by writing a few tests.

Comment: if the sum of `5` numbers is `20` can we get an average value not equal to `4`?

Comment: @arunmoezhi It appears he is not finding the average of the list of numbers, despite what he said in the post.  That said, I have no idea what he's actually calling the "average."

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a generic answer for converting recursion into iteration.  It's just resolving bugs in your code.

1. Get rid of `getCombination()`, it doesn't do anything useful.  If it is important that there be no zeroes, at least call the method something like "regenerateListIfThereAreAnyZeroes".  Or just improve the generation logic (see point 2).
2. Create a method `generateListOfNumbers()` that generates a list whose sum is 20.  There's no need to use five totally random numbers and hope; improve the logic so that (for example)

   1. the first number is mostly random (0 to 16, maybe);
   2. the second, third and fourth numbers, when added to the existing total, add up to something under (20 - existingTotal);
   3. the fifth number is whatever is required to get the total to 20.
3. Create a method `boolean isAverageInRange(double floor, double ceiling)` that provides that interesting logic you've implemented (*average += ((j + 1) * n.get(j));*, etc)
4. Change the main method to loop, calling `generateListOfNumbers()` until `isAverageInRange()` returns true.

As an additional exercise, you could create methods `decreaseAverage()` and `increaseAverage()` that modify the existing list instead of creating a whole new one each time.  That would be worth oodles of credit from your teacher, I bet.

For future reference, there is another Stack Exchange site [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that is may be useful, if you get your code working but want to improve it.